Changing employers on O1A
What are the necessary steps and documentation required if we want to change employers when on an O1A visa? Posting here since there is very little information on this matter on the web.
The website say that the requirements for submitting I-129 for O1 are:

A written consultation from a peer group or labor and/or management organization with expertise in the field.
Evidence of the beneficiary’s extraordinary ability or achievement in the field of expertise.

1 and 2 pretty much seem to be all the documentation I submitted in my original petition. My question is, does that mean for applying for I-129 will pretty much involve repeating all the steps for my original O1A petition? If it isn't the same, then how is it different?

Based on this, the requirement seems straightforward: the new employer files Form I-129 with the USCIS office listed on the form instructions. Is there something more you wanted to know?

@Traveller: Added more details to my original question.

Any updates on this, still searching for the answer.
